# Time complexity in c (nested loop)

Tags: c, loops, nested, time-complexity, nested-loops

It is so hard for me to figure out time complexity of these 2 codes.

```
c = 0;
for (i = 0; i < n*n; i++) 
for (j = 0; j < i; j++) 
 c = c + 1;
```

In the code above the outer loop's time complexity is n^2 , but it is hard to find in inner loop.

```
j = 1; c = 0;
for(i = 1; i <= n; i = i + 1) { 
 for(k = 1; k <= j; k = k + 1) { 
 c = c + 1; 
 } 
j = j * 2; 
}
```

In the second code I thought the time complexity of outer loop is n and inner loop is 2^n.
And I thought the multiple of these two ((n)*2^n) is the whole time complexity.
Is it right?
thank you for reading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first code, you are iterating from 1 to n^2. This means you are iterations are 0, 1, 2, 3, ........n*n - 1. This series in AP.

```
 Sum of series in AP = N(N+1)/2 = n^2(n^2+1)/2
 Time Complexity is O(n^4)
```

In the second code, you are iterating from 1 to n. So, the inner loop will iterate accordingly 1, 2, 4,...2^n. This series is in GP

```
 Sum of series in GP = a(r^n-1)/r-1 = 2^n
 Time complexity is O(2^n)
```

Comment: could you explain the time complexity of second code?

Comment: I think it should be O(n*2^n)because of first loop

Comment: When i = 1, the inner loop is running for 1 time, i = 2 inner loop = 2, i = 3 inner loop = 4, and so on i = n inner loop = 2^n. If you observer we are using i and getting iterations of each inner loop. So, no need to add outer loop value.

Answer (score 1):

The first one has O(n^4), because of (n*n)^2. The second one has O(n * 2n)=O(n^2).